# makeCopy() method in Google Apps Script creates a copy in my drive instead of the clients drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon

The Google Sheets add-on should create a copy of the file in the clients drive instead it creates a copy in the origin drive.

The following script in my Code.gs file should do this but does not seem to be working as intended:

```
function createACopy(id){
  var docName = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName();
  incrementDownloadCount(id);
  return DriveApp.getFileById(id).makeCopy(docName).getUrl();
}

function incrementDownloadCount(id){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var pos =data.map(function (obj) { return obj[0]; }).indexOf(id)
  if(pos > -1){
    var val = sheet.getRange("J"+(pos+2)).getValue()+1;
    sheet.getRange("J"+(pos+2)).setValue(val);
  }
}
```

here is the script in the HTML file:

```
    function makeACopy(){
    $("#templtDtl button").remove();
    $("#templtDtl").prepend(
            "<div id='copying'><img src='https://cdn.spreadsheet123.com/images/app/loading.gif' style='float:left;margin-right: 10px;'/>Making a copy...</div>"
    );
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterMakingCopy).createACopy(DETAIL[0]);
}

function afterMakingCopy(url){
    $("#copying").remove();
    $(document.createElement("div"))
            .html(
                    'File has been successfully copied to your Google Drive! Open the file by clicking on the button below, or check your Google Drive for the file named:<br/> "'+DETAIL[4]+'"<br/><br/>'+
                            "<a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'><button class='action' style='margin-left: 0px'>Open file</button></a>"
            )
            .prependTo($("#templtDtl"));
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div id="section3" style="display:none;">
            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <button onClick="backButtonPressed(3)">◄ Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="scrollable-wrapper" style="padding:10px 4px;height:320px;">
                <div id="templtTitle"></div>
                <div id="templtImg"><div id="templtThumb"></div></div>
                <div id="templtDtl" style="padding-left: 26px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please let me know if you need any additional code?

Thanks

Comment: the  first id you pass as parameter in `createACopy(id)` comes from your drive?

Comment: Yes, it comes from my drive, basically, I use a spreadsheet as DB, which includes the ID of the templates that can be downloaded via the add-on, so this is where ID is taken from.

Comment: can you try from with an id coming from the user's drive. I would do that to see if that could cause the problem.

Comment: Not sure how I can do that, I have tried getting rid of the incrementDownloadCount(id) function and got rid of the call to it in the createACopy(), though maybe this was permission issue, but nothing has changed

Comment: Sorry can't help you with that good luck

Comment: @JSmith, For some reason it all started to work, so the template is being copied to the user drive, but I have an error in the console and `afterMakingCopy` is not triggered

Comment: try withFailureHandler and display message

Comment: `withFailureHandler` did not work, the template is copied, but the add-on was continually stuck in loading. The problem with the version that is published is similar, except that it uses `withSuccessHandler`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184530/discussion-between-jsmith-and-alexb).

Comment: I'm on the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184530/discussion-between-jsmith-and-alexb) if you want

Comment: "For some reason it all started to work, ..." please update the question.